# docker on Mac, mounting volume on any directory fails " Mounts denied: EOF"

Tags: macos, docker

a co-worker is having troubles getting any docker volumes to mount on his Mac.  It works fine for me, but not him.

we both have same version of Catalina + docker 2020-03-31 2.2.0.5

`docker run hello-world` works as expected.

from home directory:
`docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/test alpine /bin/sh`

runs fine for me but for my co-worker (in his home dir):

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: EOF.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

We have tried:

- reinstall docker
- reset to factory defaults
- putting the local dist to mount in many different directories
- `docker system prune`
- reboot of entire machine

I'm running out of things to try....

any ideas/suggestions?

things I'm considering:  older version of docker, going through the pain of setting up docker via home-brew.

Thanks!

Comment: having the same issue here, i worked around it by running a vagrant box and setting up docker in there.